# how to find similar users based on items purchsed

Tags: machine-learning, svd, cosine-similarity, recommendation-engine

I have users and products which the user has purchased, and there seems to be no ratings for the products given by users. Blow is the sample data

DATA :

```
user    products
A   111, 333, 444
B   333, 444, 555
C   555, 111, 333
D   222,333, 333,333
E   111,333,444,555
F   222,555,111
```

Can we find similar customers based on above data. Am trying to use 1 for product purchase and 0 if not like below.

```
    111 222 333 444 555
A   1   0   1   1   0
B   0   0   1   1   1
C   1   0   1   0   1
D   0   1   1   0   0
E   1   0   1   1   1
F   1   1   0   0   1
```

Using the above matrix, how do I find similar customers. expecting an output in the below format.

```
user Id     similar customers
A   E, B, C
B   E, A, F
C   A, E
E   A, B, C
F   B, D
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

df = df.set_index('user')

cvect = CountVectorizer()

cs = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(cvect.fit_transform(df['products'])),
                  columns=df.index, index=df.index)

np.fill_diagonal(cs.values, 0)

threshold = 0.66

df['similar'] = cs[cs > threshold].apply(lambda row: row.dropna().index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
In [300]: df
Out[300]:
              products       similar
user
A        111, 333, 444     [B, C, E]
B        333, 444, 555     [A, C, E]
C        555, 111, 333  [A, B, E, F]
D     222,333, 333,333            []
E      111,333,444,555     [A, B, C]
F          222,555,111           [C]
```

Comment: I already did that ... I want to find similar cutsomers based on above data

Comment: @pylearner, please provide a reproducible sample data sets and your desired data set